# Proving inequality $\frac{n}{2} < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + ... + + \frac{1}{2^{n}-1} < n$

Tags: real-analysis, induction, real-numbers

Prove the inequality $\frac{n}{2} < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + ... + + \frac{1}{2^{n}-1} < n$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0,1\}$

### My work

At first I tried to prove first half by induction

> $\frac{n}2+\frac{1}2<1+\frac{1}2+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$
>
> Which is $\displaystyle\frac{1}2+\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\frac{1}k<\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n+1}-1}\frac{1}k$
>
> And then I got this $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n+1}-1}\frac{1}k-\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\frac{1}k=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{1}{2^n+k}$
>
> And now I see no way to go on $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{1}{2^n+k}>\frac{1}2$
> where $(n>1,n\in\mathbb{N},h=\overline{0,2n})$

My math background is too low so I'm not able to prove this last inequality I've got, maybe someone knows how to?(maybe using limit's definition?) But I think there should be more simplicated solution, which I cannot find for almost 4 hours now. Thank you

Comment: Please avoid using images in your question to display math formulas. I formatted your question this time, but next time please use LaTeX.

Comment: Did you notice you wrote the same inequality on the right and on the left?

Comment: For $n=100$, $\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^{n^2-1}\frac{1}{k}\sim9.78750603604<\frac{n}2=50$

Comment: There are two different inequalities in the title and in the body of the question, only one can hold.

Comment: @shcolf In your work you mistake $2^n$ with $n^2$. Can you confirm the actual inequality you're working on is the one in the body of the question?

Comment: Yes, indeed, now it works. I hadn't seen @Hippalectryon killing the possibility it was $n^2$.

Comment: {2}^{n} I hope there are not more typos there after improvement

Comment: and Hippalectryon, your provided example contains mistake it's 2^n and NOT n^2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction.

**Basis**: $1<1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}<2.$

**Inductive step:** Assume the statement holds for $n=k$. Then we show this implies the truthfulness of $$\frac{k+1}{2}<1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1}<k+1,$$ that is $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{k}{2}<1+\sum_{i=3}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{i} \\ 
k>\sum_{i=2}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{i}
\end{array}
\right. 
.$$

Hence, given our initial assumption, if we prove $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}-1}\frac{1}{i}<1+\sum_{i=3}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{i} \\ 
\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}-1}\frac{1}{i}>\sum_{i=2}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{i}
\end{array}
\right.
\leftrightarrow \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{2}<\sum_{i=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{i} \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)\\ 
1>\sum_{i=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{i} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{array}
\right. $$
we are done.
Since $\sum_{i=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{i}$ obviously decreases as $k$ increases, $(2)$ holds for all $k\ge2$ as we can check that $$1>\sum_{i=4}^7\frac{1}{i}=\frac{319}{420}. $$

As for $(1)$, it is true because the sum approaches $\log 2>\frac{1}{2}$ from above. Indeed we have $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{i}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{i}-\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}-1}\frac{1}{i}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{i}-\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}}\frac{1}{i}=\\\lim_{k\to\infty}(k+1)\log2-\lim_{k\to\infty}k\log2=\log2,$$
 where we used $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}}{\log n}=1.$
Thus we conclude the statement holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0;1\}.$

Comment: Sorry for answering only now but I had to eat lunch.

Comment: Great! Thanks man.

Comment: @shcolf Glad I could help, thank you for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{1}{n}\geq \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$, it follows that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2^N-1}\frac{1}{n}\geq\sum_{n=1}^{2^N-1}\left(\log(n+1)-\log(n)\right) = \log 2^N = N \log 2.$$
On the other hand, $\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\frac{1}{2n^2}$ gives:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2^N-1}\frac{1}{n}\leq N \log 2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}= N\log 2+\frac{\pi^2}{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove the first inequality, group them $$1+(\frac12)+(\frac13+\frac14)+(\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18)+...$$
so each group goes from one power of two to the next.  Show that each group's sum is more than $1/2$.
To prove the second, group them $$1 + (\frac12+\frac13)+(\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac17)+...$$
again, each group goes from one power of two to the next.  Each group's sum is less than $1$.

Comment: a summation of my last provided inequality exactly does that "grouping" thing, I just dont know how to proceed

Comment: (1/3+1/4)>(1/4+1/4)=1/2; (1/2+1/3)<(1/2+1/2)=1

Comment: Ah, now got it, gotta get pen&paper

Comment: Can this be complete step for good solution then?

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} < \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{1}{2^{n}+k} < \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$

Comment: That is the general idea.  The upper bound should be $2^n$ rather than $2n$.  Also this sum has $2^n+1$ terms; $1/(2^n+0)=1/(2^{n-1}+2^{n-1})$ so those terms will appear twice in the final sum.  That was why I did two different groupings for the two inequalities.

Comment: Thanks man, helped out really :)